# Report form not showing in VS 2013

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm a newbie to a large project. I need to edit a report form. As i know it was made in newer version of VS and it used an earlier framework for form and as i know it have something with devwxpress. When i try to open it it only showing me an error:

```
Combo box and drop down controls cannot be created via automation.
```

But it still running well in debugging mode. And that's all. Anybody knows why it is causing?

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q470436), I think your project was developed using DevExpress < 12.2, and you're trying to open/edit a DevExpress report on Visual Studio > 2012.

This way, even you could edit some forms that uses DevExpress components, you will not be able to edit DevExpress Reports. I had the same result here, lot of googling with no avail